# How can I reuse an angular material table headers and styling in a component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, reusability, angular-material-table

I am creating a site with angular where I have multiple tables with different columns. For example a table displaying something with checkboxes, other with text and so on. But all of them share the same styling,  headers and container.

So my first attempt was to create a new component with the following html:

```html
<div class="component-container">

    <ng-container *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
        <app-loading-spinner></app-loading-spinner>
    </ng-container>

    <div class="table-container">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

            <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
            
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

            <!-- Empty dataset -->
            <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow [ngClass]="{'empty-dataset__hidden': isLoadingResults}" class="empty-dataset">
                <td class="mat-cell" [colSpan]="displayedColumns.length">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="!errorLoadingResults">
                        <div class="empty-dataset__no_content">
                            <span>
                                {{emptyDatasetText ? emptyDatasetText : ""}}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="errorLoadingResults">
                        <div class="empty-dataset__error">
                            <span >
                                {{errorGettingDatasetText ? errorGettingDatasetText : ""}}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I expected to be able to inject my columns in the `ng-content`:

```html
<app-table-setting 
            [dataSource]="categories"
            [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns"
            [isLoadingResults]="isLoadingResults"
            emptyDatasetText="No categories found."
            errorGettingDatasetText="There was an error getting the categories."
            >

            <!-- ID Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                    <span class="mobile-label">ID: </span>
                    {{element.id}} 
                </td>
                <span class="mobile-label">ID: </span>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <span class="mobile-label">Name: </span>
                    {{element.name}}  
                    <div *ngIf="element.parentCategory">
                        <span class='subtitle'><span>{{element.categoryName}}</span></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Description Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                    <span class="mobile-label">Description: </span>
                    {{element.description}} 
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Symbol color -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Color </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  
                    <span class="mobile-label">Color: </span>
                    <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': element.color}" class="icon">stop</mat-icon> 
                </td>
            </ng-container>      

            <!-- Actions -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                    <span class="mobile-label">Actions: </span>    
                    <div >
                        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" id="{{'edit:' + element.id}}">
                            <mat-icon  class="icon" aria-label="Edit" (click)="onEditCategory(element.id)">edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" id="{{'delete:' + element.id}}">
                            <mat-icon class="icon" (click)="onDeleteCategory(element.id, element.name)">delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
                                
        </app-table-setting>
```

Is it possible to get that html in a reusable way and not have it duplicated for each component?

UPDATE: To avoid missunderstandings:

I have n components like this:

`Component 1`:

```
table + styling
-> columns (with different bindings and actions, not just text)
-> Some default errors/warnings with empty table
```

And I want this:

`Component 1`

```
table + styling
<ng-content>
-> Some default errors/warnings with empty table
```

`component n`

```
<app-component-1>
-> columns (with different bindings and actions, not just text)
</app-component-1>
```

**Update2**: Is the first time I create a project in stackblitz so I hope it is accesible to everyone. I have an example where if I try to place one column, the column `postion`, in the calling component the first one is not able to recognize it. I would like to know how could I do that splitting in two components:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-component-table?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You want the same table with different columns so you need to pass display columns dynamically and table render only those columns. Also, you can manipulate data source and pass as per your need. I have created one demo for you.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-731yvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I was looking for. You are using the same columns and content for each table and then filtering which column you want to display. But all columns are defined in the table component. I would like to split the code so that in your example I could call the `table` component from the `app` component having in the `app` component the code for `ID` and `education`, and in a second component have the code for `gender` and `age`. Otherwise my table component grows to thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following pattern to encapsulate your table into a component with properties and styling.

1. Create a new component, say TableSettingsComponent.
2. Copy SCSS styles into the style sheet file table-settings.component.scss.
3. Copy your HTML table into the HTML file table-settings.component.html.

Implement the component including the property accessors and setters.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-settings',
  templateUrl: './table-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-settings.component.scss']
})
export class TableSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  _dynamicColumns: any;

  @Input("_dynamicColumns")
  set _dynamicColumns(value: any) 
  { 
      this._dynamicColumns = value; 
  }

  get dynamicColumns() { return this._dynamicColumns; }
  ...

}
```

In your app module, declare your component as shown:

```
import { TableSettingsComponent } from '../components/table-settings.component.html';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    PaginationComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: 
  [
    ...
    PaginationComponent,
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You should now be able to re-use the new (child) component contained within another host (parent) component within your application. For example, within the app root component we define the column variable that will be used as input for your child table settings component. In the example below I define a string array to hold the column names:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  _columnsValue: string[];

  get columnsValue() { return this._columnsValue; }

  ngOnInit()
  {
      _columnsValue = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']; 
  }  
  ...
}
```

In the parent component's HTML (app.component.html), re-use the above component as follows, passing in values to your table component columns property as shown:

```
<app-table-settings [dynamicColumns]="columnsValue">
</app-table-settings>
```

This is just a basic structure which can be extended.
You could use any other component in your app to host the new component.

Please try and see how it goes.

Comment: I think this is similar to what I tried, but when I was declaring the columns in the HTML with `matColumnDef` inside the tags calling `app-table-settings`, as you have shown, I had an error in the browser console that the column name could not be found.

Comment: I think I was able to build a reproducible example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-component-table?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Your column name will need to be declared within the parent component TS source as a variable before it can be used as an input into the new table (child) component from the parent component HTML template.

Comment: could you update the response to show this. I have been trying for a while, but I'm not able to make ti work.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include clarity on how the parent component would work with a contained child component. Just use the basic case with one property as I showed and get that to work first before extending.